# Pandas: Filtering on describe output (count)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to limit the output returned by the describe output to a subset of only those records with a count great than or equal to any given number.

My dataframe is a subset of a larger one, and is defined as:

```
 df = evaluations[['score','garden_id']]
```

When I run describe on this,

```
df.groupby('garden_id').describe()
```

I would like to filter the returned data to those records where count > a specified number.

My output looks like:

```
Out[39]: 
                 score
garden_id             
37254     count      6
          mean      20
          std        0
          min       20
          25%       20
          50%       20
          75%       20
          max       20
37273     count      1
          mean      17
          std      NaN
          min       17
          25%       17
          50%       17
          75%       17
          max       17
37284     count      1
          mean      19
          std      NaN
          min       19
          25%       19
          50%       19
          75%       19
          max       19
37288     count      1
          mean      11
          std      NaN
          min       11
          25%       11
          50%       11
               ...
```

I was going to try modifying something like: [modify-output-from-python-pandas-describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124148/modify-output-from-python-pandas-describe), but I only get this:

```
Out[40]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [score]
Index: []
```

when I run `df.groupby('garden_id').describe().loc[['count']]`

I did try `newframe = df.groupby('garden_id').describe().count() > 3`, but I get a mask showing which records are true and which false, so not really sure how to use this, either.

Is there a way I can filter out desired records directly using the `describe` method without having to deal with data masking, etc.?

Comment: .@horcle What is the output you are after?

Comment: @jezrael apparently understood what I wanted: I want to set a threshold for the counts in the describe output, and then find out which garden_ids match this criterion.

Comment: .@horcle. You are not  limiting the output of .describe(). The output are the same.

Comment: And, I didn't want just the counts: I also wanted all the other summary statistics associated with each garden_id.

Comment: @Merlin, I edited the question to reflect what I really was looking to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for selecting and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for finding `index` `idx1`, where mask is `True`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score':[1,2,3,3,1,2],
                   'garden_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2]})

print (df)
   garden_id  score
0          1      1
1          1      2
2          1      3
3          1      3
4          2      1
5          2      2

newframe = df.groupby('garden_id').describe()
print (newframe)
                    score
garden_id                
1         count  4.000000
          mean   2.250000
          std    0.957427
          min    1.000000
          25%    1.750000
          50%    2.500000
          75%    3.000000
          max    3.000000
2         count  2.000000
          mean   1.500000
          std    0.707107
          min    1.000000
          25%    1.250000
          50%    1.500000
          75%    1.750000
          max    2.000000
```

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
mask = newframe.loc[idx[:,'count'],:] > 3
print (mask)
                 score
garden_id             
1         count   True
2         count  False

idx1 = mask[mask.values].index.get_level_values('garden_id')
print (idx1)
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64', name='garden_id')

print (newframe.loc[idx[idx1,:],:])
                    score
garden_id                
1         count  4.000000
          mean   2.250000
          std    0.957427
          min    1.000000
          25%    1.750000
          50%    2.500000
          75%    3.000000
          max    3.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for counts of score greater than 3 
  Try this:

```
df2 =  df.groupby('garden_id').count()
df2[df2['score']> 3]
```